# I want to bend the corners of a square sheet to 90 degrees as follows. How should i do it?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

The details to the problem are given in the picture. As you can see I am trying to bend the corners of a plate but I'm unable to give a bend to all corners in one pass.  Could someone suggest a complete solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: you can use mirror modifier http://prntscr.com/jtstja then you only fold 1

second option is "fold" each corner and add the keyframes at the same frame and time

Comment: But how should i use the bend modifier?? Its distorting not only the corners but plane surface too !!

Comment: ..I wish I'd had someone like the teacher who set this assignment ... cunning devil!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Simple Deform > Bend modifier IMO, is not easy to get your head around.

1. Create a plane, extending from 0 to its dimension in X and Y, with its origin at world 0.
2. Cut its outer corner (<kbd>K</kbd>, holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to constrain to the center of the edges)
3. Bevel the cut.

[image]

4. Select the inner crease, and (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>), place the 3D cursor there.
5. Create an empty, rotate to the orientation shown, and put the cursor back where it came from

[image]

6. Assign a Bend modiifer. The space in which it operates, here, is defined by the empty. From what I've deduced by trial and error, this is what happens, when set as shown:

   a) In *the modifier's space*, rotations of the vertices of the modified object will be around Z.

   b) The extent of the modified object in X of the modifier's space is mapped onto a range of 1, with 0 set to the space's origin. So if 2/3 of the object is in negative X, its furthest negative point in X will be mapped to -0.66, and furthest positive to 0.33.

   c) Each vertex will be rotated by its mapped position in X, multiplied by the total rotation requested in the modifier.

As far as I can tell, the 'Limits' setting also  refers to a mapped range of 1, but *with a different origin*. This time, 0 is mapped to the furthest negative point, and 1 to the furthest positive point, in the modifier's X. That's the best way I can explain to myself why the settings shown work the way they do.

[image]

Anyway, this is the result:

[image]

Now you can add a Mirror (X & Y)  and a Solidify modifier...

[image]

... parent the empty and the plane to another empty, (here I've raised it in Z, in case you want some 'pendulum' rotations in the animation)..

[image]

For safety, lock off all the transformations of the modifier empty and the plane, placing them under sole control of the parent empty, and you're good to go.