# How to animate after simple deform?

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes

I want to animate a [folding sheet](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110579/30849):

[image]

I locked the locrotscale without any bend that is at deform bend angle =0°. 
But when I change this angle to 90° for the next key frame the object seems to capture the angle and apply to the intial key frame, which I have animated with 0°.

Comment: Are you dead set on a bend modifier? I would definitely suggest armatures instead.

Comment: I am actually working with an empty set of arrows and using them as a bend entity !

Comment: You've got to key frame the angle within the modifier itself ... right-click the' Angle' field >insert key frame..  say, a key frame for 0 degrees at frame 1, and  another for 90 degrees at frame 100 ..

Answer (score 1):

You can deform the object to it's final shape first, and then you select APPLY AS SHAPE KEY.

Then, go to the vertex group menu, and select SIMPLE DEFORM under SHAPE KEYS

Finally, you will see a slider named VALUE. turn automatic keyframe on, and then start deforming the object through time.

In that way you don't even need armatures