# Is it possible to animate 2 folds on the same sheet?

Tags: animation, bones, vertex-groups

As can be seen on the screen shot, I want to animate first folding the top right triangle and then along the center line of the sheet using the 2nd bigger bone. and then a third fold of the left side triangle. However when I do my second fold the whole sheet scrambles up. Some of the vertices from the two assigned grouped overlap, so I am not sure if this is the problem for blender. What is the correct way to make this work, or maybe it is just not possible in Blender?

[image]

Comment: Vertices should only be 100% assigned to a single bone. Remove the influences of the large bone from the selected vertices.

Comment: And the triangle bone should be child of the centerline bone.

Comment: You might also consider using a method somewhat like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110579/35559)

Answer (score 6):

Assign only the needed vertices (tips) for each bone as follows:

[image]

And then you should fold it beautifully.

[image]